# Is it a valid way to write redux actions and reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've built a cards war game. I'm new to redux and wonder if I use it the correct way, especially when I declare actions in the Game and Main components, and use action's payloads as callbacks to update the state. Also, It feels like a lot of code for a small app. Maybe you can help guys and give me some insights if i'm doing it the wrong way and why, thanks. I put here the relevant components and the full code is here:
https://github.com/morhaham/cards-war-redux

store.js:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const state = {
  game_ready: false,
  cards: [],
  player: { name: "", cards: [], points: 0 },
  computer: { name: "computer", cards: [], points: 0 },
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INIT_GAME_CARDS":
      return action.payload(state);
    case "UPDATE_PLAYER_NAME":
      return action.payload(state);
    case "SET_GAME_READY":
      return action.payload(state);
    case "DIST_CARDS":
      return action.payload(state);
    case "SET_NEXT_CARDS":
      return action.payload(state);
    case "INCREASE_POINTS":
      return action.payload(state);
    case "RESET_GAME":
      return action.payload(state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducer, state);

export default store;
```

Main.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { NUM_OF_CARDS, MAX_CARD_VALUE } from "./constants";
import { shuffle } from "./helpers";

// action creator to initialize the game
const initGameCards = () => ({
  type: "INIT_GAME_CARDS",
  payload: (state) => {
    // creates an array of size 52 filled with 1..13 four times
    const cards = Array(NUM_OF_CARDS / MAX_CARD_VALUE)
      .fill(
        Array(13)
          .fill()
          .map((_, i) => i + 1)
      )
      .flat();
    // shuffle the cards
    shuffle(cards);
    return {
      ...state,
      cards,
    };
  },
});

// action creator to control the player's name
const updatePlayerName = (name) => ({
  type: "UPDATE_PLAYER_NAME",
  payload: (state) => ({
    ...state,
    player: { ...state.player, name: name },
  }),
});

const setGameReady = () => ({
  type: "SET_GAME_READY",
  payload: (state) => ({
    ...state,
    game_ready: true,
  }),
});

function Main() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const player = useSelector(({ player }) => player);
  // const game_ready = useSelector(({ game_ready }) => game_ready);

  const handleClick = React.useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (player.name) {
        dispatch(setGameReady());
        history.replace("./game");
      }
    },
    [dispatch, player.name]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(initGameCards());
  }, []);

  const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const val = target.value;
    switch (target.id) {
      case "playerName":
        dispatch(updatePlayerName(val));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {/* check for valid input */}
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="playerName">
          <h1 className="text-blue-800 text-5xl text-shadow-lg mb-3">
            Ready for war
          </h1>
        </label>
        <input
          className="border focus:ring-2 focus:outline-none"
          id="playerName"
          required
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter your name"
          type="text"
          value={player.name}
        />
        {!player.name ? (
          <p className="text-red-700">Please fill the field</p>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <Button
          onClick={handleClick}
          type="submit"
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
        >
          Start
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Game.js:

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { NUM_OF_CARDS } from "./constants";
import { shuffle } from "./helpers";

// action creator to distribute the cards at the beginning of the game
const distCards = () => ({
  type: "DIST_CARDS",
  payload: (state) => {
    const cards = [...state.cards];
    shuffle(cards);
    const computer_cards = cards.slice(0, NUM_OF_CARDS / 2);
    const player_cards = cards.slice(NUM_OF_CARDS / 2);
    const computer_current_card = computer_cards.pop();
    const player_current_card = player_cards.pop();
    return {
      ...state,
      cards,
      // distributes cards evenly
      computer: {
        ...state.computer,
        cards: computer_cards,
        current_card: computer_current_card,
        points: 0,
      },
      player: {
        ...state.player,
        cards: player_cards,
        current_card: player_current_card,
        points: 0,
      },
    };
  },
});

const setNextCards = () => ({
  type: "SET_NEXT_CARDS",
  payload: (state) => {
    let [computer_cards, player_cards] = [
      [...state.computer.cards],
      [...state.player.cards],
    ];
    const [computer_next_card, player_next_card] = [
      computer_cards.pop(),
      player_cards.pop(),
    ];
    return {
      ...state,
      player: {
        ...state.player,
        cards: player_cards,
        current_card: player_next_card,
      },
      computer: {
        ...state.computer,
        cards: computer_cards,
        current_card: computer_next_card,
      },
    };
  },
});

const pointsIncreament = () => ({
  type: "INCREASE_POINTS",
  payload: (state) => {
    const [player_current_card, computer_current_card] = [
      state.player.current_card,
      state.computer.current_card,
    ];
    return {
      ...state,
      player: {
        ...state.player,
        points:
          player_current_card > computer_current_card
            ? state.player.points + 1
            : state.player.points,
      },
      computer: {
        ...state.computer,
        points:
          player_current_card < computer_current_card
            ? state.computer.points + 1
            : state.computer.points,
      },
    };
  },
});

function Game() {
  const player = useSelector(({ player }) => player);
  const computer = useSelector(({ computer }) => computer);
  const game_ready = useSelector(({ game_ready }) => game_ready);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleReset = React.useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(distCards());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (game_ready) {
      dispatch(distCards());
    } else {
      history.replace("/");
    }
  }, [game_ready]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (player.current_card && computer.current_card) {
      dispatch(pointsIncreament());
    }
  }, [player.current_card, computer.current_card]);

  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(setNextCards());
  });

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div>
          <div>{player.name}</div>
          <div>Points: {player.points}</div>
          <div>{player.current_card}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>{computer.current_card}</div>
          <div>Points: {computer.points}</div>
          <div>{computer.name}</div>
        </div>
        {!player.cards.length || !computer.cards.length ? (
          <Button
            onClick={handleReset}
            type="submit"
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
          >
            Again?
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <Button
            onClick={handleClick}
            type="submit"
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
          >
            next
          </Button>
        )}
        <div>
          {!player.cards.length || !computer.cards.length ? (
            player.points === computer.points ? (
              <h2>It's a tie</h2>
            ) : player.points > computer.points ? (
              <h2>{player.name} won!</h2>
            ) : (
              <h2>{computer.name} won!</h2>
            )
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: I *guess* this could work, but it seems you are missing the point of redux by quite a bit. The reducer function is what maintains control over the state slice, the actions are to only inform the reducer what logic, or "action", to take and operate over the state. You should centralize all the logic to the reducer, not distribute them across all the actions. You should also try to split all the nested state out each into their own state slice reducers where it makes sense.

Comment: You just made the reason to use redux redundant. In redux an action indicates that something happened and the reducer or middleware has the implementation of what needs to be done when a certain action happened. So redux separates things that happen with the implementation of needs to be done when something happens. The way you wrote your redux code you'd be better off using React context api. Redux is an event store and as such [has certain perks](https://www.eventstore.com/blog/what-is-event-sourcing) over other designs.

Comment: You also break [redux devtools support](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants) by creating non serializable actions that reach your reducer (not handled by middleware): `Actions only need to be serializable by the time they actually reach the store and are passed to the reducers.`